# HttpMessageConverter for Type zipFile on performing RestTemplate Call

Tags: resttemplate, zip

I am trying to download a ZipFile from a server. This Will be a REST call. The response of REST call is a ZipFile. Now on performing the below code i am getting following error -

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.util.zip.ZipFile] and content type [application/zip]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:619)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:377)
at com.i3l.finnair.bpm.common.qualtrics.helper.QualtricsAPIHelper.qualtricsResponseExportFile(QualtricsAPIHelper.java:262)
at com.i3l.finnair.css.surveyresults.test.QualtricsTest.processCustomerSurveyResponse(QualtricsTest.java:121)
at com.i3l.finnair.css.surveyresults.test.QualtricsTest.main(QualtricsTest.java:28)
```

my rest call is like below -

```
public static ZipFile qualtricsResponseExportFile(String surveyExportRespId, String _apiToken){

    String restUrl = "https://eu.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseexports/{surveyExportRespId}/file";
    HttpHeaders headers = getRESTHeader(_apiToken);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplateWithJsonConverter();
    HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(headers);
    ResponseEntity<ZipFile> response = restTemplate
            .exchange(restUrl, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity,
                    ZipFile.class, surveyExportRespId);
    ZipFile responseFile = response.getBody();
    return responseFile;
}
```

my restHeader is like below -

```
private static HttpHeaders getRESTHeader(String _apiToken) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("X-API-TOKEN", _apiToken);
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return headers;
}
```

my RestConverter is like below -

```
private static RestTemplate getRestTemplateWithJsonConverter() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    // Create a list for the message converters
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    // Add the Jackson Mapping JSON Message converter
    messageConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    // Add the message converters to the restTemplate
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This article helped me: https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/038-retrieve-file-spring-resttemplate/

First of all you have to set the request headers to accept all type of response.

```
requestHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));
```

After this, add the ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter to your message converters.

```
messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
```

And finally, retrieve the file as byte array wrapped into a ResponseEntity.

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate
            .exchange(restUrl, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity,
                    byte[].class, surveyExportRespId);
```

Byte array can be saved as a file, or deserialize your ZipFile entity.